# Java JSON object - How to get the result from Facebook for a given permission in the respone, or if the value is 1 or 0

Tags: java, json, facebook-graph-api

Below is a query for permissions -  I am trying to see if a specific perm is granted.. Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
 JSONObject permissions = new JSONObject(
                         IOUtil.urlToString(new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions?access_token=AAACEdEose0cBALhOmvDd14yIJQUTZAJ4GxFmkaHQmGKfwBwS1I32GAIsJolPZAgqB3prnVXqrvwlInYxcutnOOVFdRY6RBcgWfGT46KrSgMzdjnG6U")));



Here is the sample responce {"data": [
{
  "installed": 1,
  "user_likes": 1,
  "publish_stream": 1,
  "user_interests": 1,
  "user_hometown": 1,
  "user_groups": 1,
  "type": "permissions"
}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the "installed" value:

```
permissions.getJSONObject("data").getInt("installed");
```

Then do your comparisons as required.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @dave_newton -  what is the best way to do the comparison?

Comment: @HollySmith Remember to [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so future visitors with similar problems know what to do! Glad you got it working :)